# Ads not loading in firefox windows 7/8/10 with ABP plugin, disabled on my site only - availableWidth=0

Tags: html, css, firefox, ads, adblock

It has come to my attention that ads are not showing up on my site with Firefox and ABP-plugin, disabled on my site only.
 (bbtsip.tv/home.html) I have an approved ad-sense account.

this is the inspector error: TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0

> I have gone to [AdSense Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/CC3mT5maKoY;context-place=starred) thinking that the 'AdSense Help
>   Forum' wold be the right place to go for help with "ads" not loading,
>   but i was very wrong abut that. it is for "easy answers to easy
>   questions only" if the questions is a bit more complex they will try
>   to answer the question by telling you about anther problems and
>   avoiding the main issue! at all cost, even to the point they ignore
>   you compliantly. i do not recommend seeking help from there, all the
>   answers 'AdSense Help Forum' can give you, can be fund online without
>   beaning insulted or ignored!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9jA2.jpg)

A list of tests i did on my site

1. I can see the ads with Firefox on my PC at my website in the "website
2. editor" with on problem.  but after publishing the site the ads don't show up.
3. I have access to another site from the same site builder, and i see ads good in website editor.  and after publishing the site ads show up good, from my pc.
4. No  proxy.
5. Home ISP "savilian".
6. Ads block at the router. no not this i can see ads.
7. Internet cafes, not using one.
8. The government blocks access to ads so it might depend on the country,
    again not this i can see ads.
9. your computer settings, more than one pc also one is freshly installed.
10. your browser settings, again not this i can see ads.
11. I have tried a difference ISP connection same problem.
12. when i used this code in my site the ads show up Not good,
       mining the ads don't all load every i refresh sometimes 2 ads show up
       sometimes 3 and a lot of times none at all, like in this example:

style

```
        .example_responsive_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
        @media(min-width: 500px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
        @media(min-width: 800px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- example_responsive_1 -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle example_responsive_1"
             style="display:inline-block"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXX11XXX9"
             data-ad-slot="8XXXXX1"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
```

Is it only me or does it feels like a pattern.  is there any solution to fix this?
it looks like it all is pointing to something in the HTML or CSS maybe JS.
please enlighten me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I am back with an update/answer: the script that was causing the my problem is 100% Adsense issue! the mobile ad code below is my problem.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

the mobile ad code above is causing the problem with the responsive ad code below

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- reponsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

it is an Adsense script for mobile ads in the header of my site and it is causing the "`error: TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0`"

I still do not know if it is possible to run the to codes together in a different setup, I will update.